# Does it makes any sense, my computer can run only 4 thread in parallel?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I did try to do `hardware_concourrency` in cpp, and the result was `4` but it doesn't make any sense to me.  I've tried to operate 250 threads running in parallel, and each one connects to an other socket on the LAN and it's working pretty well.

So, I don't understand it, if the system is saying to me that I can run only 4 threads parallel, how could I operate 250 threads?

Comment: ***I did try to do hardware_concourrency in cpp, and the result was 4 but it doesn't make any sense to me.*** How many cores (and threads if you have HyperThreading) does your processor have?

Comment: ***how could I operate 250 threads?** Each thread gets a slice of time. The scheduler will alternate between which threads execute on your processors cores / threads (SMT will have more than 1 execution thread per core).

Comment: so many downvotes for a question that is not that bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should known the difference between parallel and concurrency. Parallel means that computer run jobs in same time, concurrency means computer run jobs in a period time that people can't feel.

Answer (score 5):

Only 4 CPU cores. Any more threads won't run in parellel and will simply be alternated between at high speed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between hardware threads and software threads.
The OS can run a lot of threads in parallel but the execution will be only done for 4 of them.

It is like Call waiting on phones: you talk to person a, person b calls, you answer person b. You can talk only to one of them but can switch between calls without closing them.

Same with threads: the OS keeps all of them open, with resources allocated, but splits the CPU time between them by allocating small chunks of time.

Answer (score 1):

The point is: your **software** threads will probably spent a lot of time **waiting**. For example for incoming data from IO; like data read from disks; or coming over the network.

If you restrict yourself to the *small n* number of "real HW" threads that your CP supports ... then you are losing a lot of potential gains in throughput.

In other words: the potential benefits of using a *high m* number of software stacks very much depend on your workload situation.

When your application is mainly doing IO related activities, then more threads mean that "waiting" time is spent more reasonable.

But when your application is mainly doing CPU intensive computations, then there isn't so much to be gained from a high number of threads.